# Connect signalr with react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, signalr, middleware

I am trying to develop a real time application with react-redux and signalr.

My problem become when i try to connect my react-redux app with my signalR backend, i have not my signalR client (js created by signalr backend) to use it from my react-redux app, by this i am trying to use 'ms-signalr-client' but i get jQuery errors.

Other problem is i don´t know how connect the signalr connection with my acctions and reducres, i was looking and i saw that i can create a middleware to get the recived events but i dont know how call my acctions to send data to my server.

What signalr client package do you recomend me?

What is the best way to connect signalR client in the acctions and reducers?

i tried to find some example but i didn´t find any that use a npm client package or that use redux in the application.

Do you know any examples that can serve?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I have the same question, but I can't understand enough of what you wrote to be sure... Are you basically asking how/where to connect SignalR with react-redux and where can you find some examples?